# Get ID of Select Option Parent

Tags: jquery

I've got a carousel of products that have multiple `select` controls and an image for each.  Each `select` element has the same change function:

```
                $('#abcFlavor')
                .add('#furyFlavor')
                .add('#mrpFlavor')
                .add('#proFlavor')
                .change(function () {
                    //some code...
            });
```

and here's a sample of the html:

```
    <div class="shop-latest-carousel">
    <ul id="latest_products">
        <li>
            <form target="" action="..." method="post">
                <div class="product-list-item">
                    <span class="hover"></span>
                    <div class="image" id="imageABC">
                        <a>
                            <img id="ABC_grape" src="images/shop_images/ABC_grape.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details fixclear">
                        <h3>ABC</h3>
                        <label for="abcFlavor">Flavor:</label>
                        <select name="os0" id="abcFlavor">
                            <option id="grape" value="Grape">Grape $2.99 USD</option>
                            <option id="peach" value="Peach">Peach $22.99 USD</option>
                            <option id="watermelon" value="Watermelon">Watermelon $12.99 USD</option>
                            <option id="cherry" value="Cherry">Cherry $12.99 USD</option>
                            <option id="lemonade" value="Lemonade">Lemonade $5.99 USD</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <input type="image" src="~/Images/shop_images/addToCart.png" name="submit" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            $<span>52.99</span>
                            <small>$67.49</small>
                            <br /><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Flavors">
            </form>
            <!-- end ABC -->
        </li>
        <li>
            <form target="" action="..." method="post">
                <div class="product-list-item">
                    <span class="hover"></span>
                    <div class="image" id="imageFury">
                        <a>
                            <img id="img_fury_lemonlime" src="images/shop_images/Fury_lemonlime.png" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details fixclear">
                        <h3>Fury</h3>
                        <label for="furyFlavor">Flavor:</label>
                        <select name="os0" id="furyFlavor">
                            <option id="lemonline" value="Lemon-Lime">Lemon-Lime $19.99 USD</option>
                            <option id="melon" value="Melon">Melon $9.99 USD</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="actions">
                            <input type="image" src="~/Images/shop_images/addToCart.png" name="submit" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="price">
                            $<span>39.99</span>
                            <small>$47.24</small>
                            <br /><br />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Flavors">
            </form>
            <!-- end Fury -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do a switch statement on the "id" of the `select` element that fired the event (not the "id" of the selected option)?

I tried things like:

```
var sel = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

but it keeps coming back 'undefined'.

Comment: You don't need all those `.add()` calls, the `change` event only fires on the `select`, not the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the event handler callback, `this` is the DOM `select` element, so:

```
switch (this.id) {
    case "abcFlavor":
        // ...
        break;
    // and so on
}
```

Example (just showing the `id`, but at that point, of course you can `switch` on it): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/izimuy/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/izimuy/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>jQuery 'this' example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>abcFlavor: <select id="abcFlavor">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option></select></label>
  <br><label>furyFlavor: <select id="furyFlavor">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option></select></label>
  <br><label>mrpFlavor: <select id="mrpFlavor">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option></select></label>
  <br><label>proFlavor: <select id="proFlavor">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>Three</option></select></label>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $('#abcFlavor')
      .add('#furyFlavor')
      .add('#mrpFlavor')
      .add('#proFlavor')
      .change(function () {
        display("You changed " + this.id);
      });

      function display(msg) {
        $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
      }
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Side note: You can skip all those `add` calls using commas in your selector:

```
$('#abcFlavor, #furyFlavor, #mrpFlavor, #proFlavor').change(function () {
  // Code here
});
```

Comment: Or, use a single class to attach behavior to all <select class=".my-selects" /> elements that require the behavior $(".my-selects").change(function() { //Code Here 
});

Comment: Thanks TJ...I'm not very good with jQuery yet so this helped me a lot!